# What is the correct hedging strategy using futures?

Tags: hedging

In practice, even without maturity and underlying mismatch, hedging using futures does not always require a one-to-one hedge ratio. Tailing factor needs to be considered. Suppose the current spot price is $3. With 50 percent of the probability, the spot price will increase or decrease by 1 dollar for each year as shown in the graph below. If the annual discrete compounding risk-free rate is 10%, and the cost of carry offsets the convenience yield exactly, then what is your hedging strategy?

Comment: Where did the graph go?

Comment: I am unable to upload the picture

Comment: Is that perhaps a [`self-study`](http://quant.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question?